# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow  \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})} =
\frac{\frac{\cos(2x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\frac{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}}$$  and $$\begin{align}\frac{\cos(2x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} &=
\frac{\cos(2x)}{\frac{4x-\pi}{4}} \\&= 
\frac{4\cos(2x)}{4x-\pi} = \,\,???\end{align}$$

What do I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u = x-\pi/4$ then you want $$\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\cos(2(u + \pi/4))}{\sin u}=-\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin 2u}{\sin u } = -\lim_{u \to 0} 2\cos u=-2$$

Comment: You got there first with the right answer.

Comment: Just one thing, how did you get from $\cos(2(u+\pi/4))$ to $-\sin(2u)$?

Comment: @MarkRead $$\cos(2(u+\pi/4)) = \cos (2u + \pi/2) = \cos 2u \cos \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin 2u \sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 0 - 1\cdot \sin 2u =-\sin 2u$$

Comment: Right, thanks..

Comment: Alternatively, you can write it down right away from noting that $\sin$ is just a $\pi/2$ translation of $\cos. $

Comment: @ZainPatel Could you explain?

Comment: @MarkRead if you look at the graph of $\sin$ and $\cos$, you note the relation (since $\sin$ is a translation of $\cos$ by $\pi/2$ or $90^{\circ}$) $\sin x = \cos (x - \pi/2)$. But we also have $\sin(x+\pi) = \cos (x-\pi/2 + \pi) = -\cos (x + \pi/2) = -\sin x$. Now let $x=2u$ so $\cos (2u + \pi/2) = - \sin 2u$.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying this the hard way.

Let $x = \frac\pi 4 -y$. Then

$$
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\cos(2(\frac\pi 4 -y))}{\sin(- y)}
=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\cos(\frac\pi 2-2y)}{-\sin y}
=-\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin(2y)}{\sin y}
=-\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{2\sin y \cos y}{\sin y}
=-\lim_{y\to 0}2 \cos y=-2
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\cos(2x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-2x\right)\\\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}2-2x)}{x-\frac{\pi}4}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{\pi}2-2x)}{2x-\frac{\pi}2}$$
Now it should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \cos (2x), g(x) = \sin (x-\pi/4).$ The expression equals

$$\frac{f(x) - f(\pi/4)}{g(x)-g(\pi/4)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{f(x) - f(\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}}{\dfrac{g(x)-g(\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}}.$$

By definition of the derivative and basic limit laws, the last expression $\to \dfrac{f'(\pi/4)}{g'(\pi/4)}$ as $x\to \pi/4,$  an easy computation. (And no, L'Hopital was nowhere used.)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternate approach:
I said: $\frac{cos(2\theta)}{sin\theta*cos(\frac{\pi}{4})-cos\theta*(\frac{\pi}{4})}$ =

$\frac{cos(2\theta)}{1/\sqrt(2)*sin\theta-cos\theta}$ Noting that $cos(2\theta)=cos^2\theta-sin^2\theta$ and $sin\theta-cos\theta=-(cos\theta-sin\theta)$
So, we have
$\frac{cos^2\theta-sin^2\theta}{-1/\sqrt(2)*(cos\theta-sin\theta)}$ = $-2*\frac{(cos\theta-sin\theta)*(\cos\theta+sin\theta)}{(cos\theta-sin\theta)}$=$-2*cos(\theta)+sin(\theta)$=-2 when you take the limit. Note that I just reciprocated the $-\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}$